# Binary tree recursive add not producing correct result

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am writing a binary search tree for practice and I'm having an issue with my recursive add.  My iterative add seems to work fine and so does my print but as soon as I add 20 and 25 to my tree using addRecursive, there are no additions that seem to be done.

This is kind of puzzling to me.  Any help would be appreciated along with explanation of course.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node {

    public: 
        int value;
        Node * left;
        Node * right;
        Node (int v, Node * l = 0, Node * r = 0) : value (v){}

};

class Tree {

    public:
        Node * top;

        Tree(){
            top = 0;
        }

        Tree (int value){
            top = new Node(value);
        }

        void add(int value);
        void addRecursive(Node * node, int value);
        void print(Node * node);
        void root();
};

void Tree::add(int value){
    if (top == NULL){
        top = new Node(value);
        return;
    }
    Node * newNode = new Node(value);
    Node * current = top;
    bool added = false;
    while (!added){
        if (value < current->value){
            if (current->left == NULL){
                current->left = newNode;
                added = true;
            }
            else {
                current = current->left;
            }
        }
        else if (value >= current->value){
            if (current->right == NULL){
                current->right = newNode;
                added = true;
            }
            else{
                current = current->right;
            }
        }
    }
}

void Tree::addRecursive(Node * node, int value){
    if (node == NULL){
        node = new Node(value);
    }
    else{
        if (value < node->value){
            addRecursive(node->left, value);
        }
        else if (value >= node->value){
            addRecursive(node->right, value);
        }
    }
    return;
}

void Tree::print(Node * node){
    if (node == NULL){
        return;
    }
    print(node->left);
    cout << node->value << " ";
    print(node->right);
}

int main(){
    Tree * tree = new Tree();
    tree->add(5);
    tree->print(tree->top);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "------------" << endl;
    tree->add(10);
    tree->add(15);
    tree->print(tree->top);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "------------" << endl;
    tree->addRecursive(tree->top, 20);
    tree->addRecursive(tree->top, 25);
    tree->print(tree->top);
}
```

Comment: We are not a replacement for your debugger :/

Comment: `node = new Node(value);` red alert, red alert, changing a local variable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void Tree::addRecursive(Node * node, int value){
    if (node == NULL){
        node = new Node(value);
    }
```

`node` here is a copy of the pointer you put in. You create a new Node and assign that to this copy, not the `tree->top` that you want to insert to.

Comment: Changing the signature to `void Tree::addRecursive(Node *& node, int value)` makes the test pass, but I do not think it is a great design.